# Unity Coroutine yield return null EQUIVALENT with Task async await

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, coroutine, .net-4.6

What is the equivalent of `yield return null;` in Coroutine (that run each frame at Update) in an async method ?

The nearest I got to find is `await Task.Delay(1);`, but it DO NOT run every frame.

```
private IEnumerator RunEachFrame()
{
    while (true)
    {
        print("Run Each frame right before rendering");
        yield return null;
    }
}

async void DoNotRunEachFrame()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1); // What is the equivalent of yield return null here ?
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You can only use Unity's API in the main thread. Maybe there is a workaround if you explain what you are doing

Comment: I am running them on the main thread: `Unity does provide one important piece for us however. As you can see in the above example, our async methods will be run on the main unity thread by default. In non-unity C# applications, async methods are often automatically run on separate threads` http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is currently **no** equivalent method for for `yield return null` .

I was going to say it's not possible since async can be called in another `Thread` other than the main `Thread` which can throw exceptions since you can't use Unity's API in another Thread but it [*looks*](https://forum.unity.com/threads/synchronizationcontext-for-main-thread.433876/) like Unity fixed the Thread issue by implementing their own async context in *Unity 5.6.0b5* and above.

---

It' still possible to do but you have to implement it yourself or use an existing API. The `UnityAsync` API can do this already. You can get it [here](https://bitbucket.org/muckSponge/unityasync). The `NextUpdate` function replaces the `yield return null` instruction.

Examples:

Your usual coroutine code:

```
private IEnumerator RunEachFrame()
{
    while (true)
    {
        print("Run Each frame right before rendering");
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

The equivalent async code:

```
using UnityAsync;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class UpdateLoop : AsyncBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        RunEachFrame();
    }

    // IEnumerator replaced with async void
    async void RunEachFrame()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            print("Run Each frame right before rendering");
            //yield return null replaced with await NextUpdate()
            await NextUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the script inherits from `AsyncBehaviour` instead of `MonoBehaviour`.

---

If you really want to inherit from `MonoBehaviour` instead of `AsyncBehaviour` and still use this API, call the `NextUpdate` function directly as `Await.NextUpdate()`.Here is a complete equivalent example:

```
using UnityAsync;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class UpdateLoop : MonoBehaviour
{
    async void Start()
    {
        await RunEachFrame();
    }

    async Task RunEachFrame()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            print("Run Each frame right before rendering");
            await Await.NextUpdate(); // equivalent of AsyncBehaviour's NextUpdate
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the complete supported wait functions:

- `NextUpdate`
- `NextLateUpdate`
- `NextFixedUpdate`
- `Updates(int framesToWait)`
- `LateUpdates(int framesToWait)`
- `FixedUpdates(int stepsToWait)`
- `Seconds(float secondsToWait)`
- `SecondsUnscaled(float secondsToWait)`
- `Until(Func<bool> condition)`
- `While(Func<bool> condition)`
- `Custom(CustomYieldInstruction instruction)`
- `AsyncOp(AsyncOperation op)`

All these can be found in the [`Await`](https://bitbucket.org/muckSponge/unityasync/src/d8ec0b13ec9c93abe00cea51040486504c5085a1/Assets/UnityAsync/Await.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) class just in-case they get renamed or removed.

If you ever run into issues with this API, see Unity's forum [post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityasync-allocation-free-async-coroutines.483880/) dedicated to it and ask questions there.

Comment: This is https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask a better alternative to the UnityAsync API.

Comment: @Markus UniTask doesn't have some equivalents, for example `WaitForEndOfFrame` doesn't work for `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture()`. 
https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask#playerloop

Answer (score 12):

At least in Unity 2018 you can use `await Task.Yield()`. For example:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class AsyncYieldTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    async void Start()
    {
        await Function();
    }
    
    async Task Function() {
        while (gameObject != null)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            Debug.Log("Frame: " + Time.frameCount);
        }
    }  
}
```

will give you output:

```
Frame: 1
Frame: 2
Frame: 3
...
```

It seems that if the `Debug.Log("Frame: " + Time.frameCount);` line was before `await Task.Yield();`, it would run twice during the first frame. I'm not sure what's the reason for that.

With [UniTask library](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask)'s `UniTask.NextFrame` it's possible to get behaviour that matches `yield return null` fully so that you don't get 2 messages on the first frame with

```
using Cysharp.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class AsyncYieldTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    async void Start()
    {
        await Function();
    }

    async UniTask Function() {
        while (gameObject != null)
        {
            // Debug.Log first like with yield return null
            Debug.Log("Frame: " + Time.frameCount);
            await UniTask.NextFrame();
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define a function that creates async task and uses a coroutine to wait for end of the frame.

```
Task<bool> WaitOneFrameAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    StartCoroutine(WaitOneFrame(tcs));
    return tcs.Task;
}

static IEnumerator WaitOneFrame(TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs)
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    tcs.TrySetResult(true);
}
```

Now you can happily use it in async function

```
await WaitOneFrameAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of these solutions:

1.

```
await UniTask.DelayFrame(1)
```

2. ```
   await UniTask.Yield()
   ```
3. ```
   await Task.Delay(150);
   ```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

I got this way:

```
private async void NextFrameCall()
{
    int currentFrame = Time.renderedFrameCount;
    while (currentFrame >= Time.renderedFrameCount)
        await Task.Yield();
        
    //NextFrameMethodHere();
}
```

Comment: Btw, on the example above I used the next RENDERED FRAME, if you want the NEXT FRAME use "Time.frameCount".